# Group Theory: Cyclic groups and Subgroup of Dihedrals, is my proof okay?

Tags: group-theory

Suppose we're given a Dihedral group $D_{30}$.
a) Find a cyclic subgroup H of order 10 in $D_{30}$. List all generators of H.
b) Let k and n be an integer such that k >= 3 and k divides n. Prove that $D_n$ contains exactly one cyclic subgroup of order k.

My attempt:
a) in $D_{30}$ we know that |r| = 30. So we can find a cyclic subgroup H generated by r such that it is of order 10. take < $r^{30/10}$ > = < $r^3$ >. Then < $r^3$ > contains the identity element e and powers of $r^3$, to $r^{27}$. Thus the generator of H is then $r^3$. Would this be okay?

b) Since k divides n, we can write n as n = kp  for some p. Then we see that gcd(n,k) = k and thus:
|< r >| =  |r| =  n.

Then by Fundamental theorem of cyclic groups I can say that the group  has exactly one subgroup of order k, ie:  =  since n =  kp. And we are done.

This is my first course in Group Theory so I'm rather shaky and insecure about my proofs. Your comments and help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: notice that you didn't use the fact that $k\geq 3$ in b. Try to find where you need it (and then correct your proof)

Comment: There are two conventions for the dihedral group. In one convention, $D_n$ is the group associated to the regular $n$-gon and has $2n$ elements. In the other, $D_{2n}$ is the dihedral group with $2n$ elements. It is always good practice to specify which one you are using (clearly, the former here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using $D_{30}$ to represent the dihedral group of order $60$, with $r$ corresponding to the "rotation", and some other element, call it $s$, the "reflection"; that is,
$$D_{30}=\left\langle r,s\Bigm| r^{30} = s^2 = 1,\quad sr = r^{-1}s\right\rangle.$$

Part (a): Your first part begins well enough, but it seems like you did not read the question carefully. The last part of part (a) asks you to find **all** generators of the subgroup $H$ you found.

You took $H=\langle r^3\rangle$. That's fine; this is a group of order $10$. But $r^3$ is not the *only* generator of this group. Perhaps you know that, in general, the cyclic group of order $n$, $C_n$ has $\varphi(n)$ generators, where $\varphi$ is Euler's function that counts the number of positive integers less than $n$ and relatively prime to $n$ (if you don't, then try to prove it). So $H$, being cyclic of order $10$, should have $\varphi(10) = 4$ generators. You've found one, there are three more to go.

Your part (b) also suffers a bit. You know that there is one and only one subgroup of $\langle r\rangle$ that has order $k$; that's fine. But you did not prove that *every* subgroup of $D_n$ of order $k$ must be a subgroup of $\langle r\rangle$! You need to show that too if you want your argument to hold. So you would need to show that the *only* elements of order $k$ all lie in $\langle r\rangle$; that's where you'll need the fact that $k\geq 3$. Perhaps you can show that every *other* element has other ideas about what their order is?

Answer (score 0):

For the first part, one solution is to use brute force as follow.

Let us consider $D_{30}$ acting on a set of cardinality $30$, generated by the two elements $(1, 2, 3, 4, 5,$ $6, 7, 8, 9, 10,$ $11, 12, 13, 14, 15,$ $16, 17, 18, 19, 20,$ $21, 22, 23, 24, 25,$ $26, 27, 28, 29, 30)$ and $(1, 30)(2, 29)(3,28)$ $(4, 27)(5, 26)(6, 25)$ $(7, 24)(8, 23)(9, 22)$ $(10, 21)(11, 20)(12, 19)$ $(13, 18)(14, 17)(15, 16)$.

Then the cyclic subgroup of order 10 of $D_{30}$ is generated by $(1, 28, 25, 22, 19,$ $16, 13, 10, 7, 4)$ $(2, 29, 26, 23, 20,$ $17, 14, 11, 8, 5)$ $(3, 30, 27, 24, 21,$ $18, 15, 12, 9, 6)$ and $(1, 25, 19, 13, 7)$ $(2, 26, 20, 14, 8)$ $(3, 27, 21, 15, 9)$ $(4, 28, 22, 16, 10)$ $(5, 29, 23, 17, 11)$ $(6, 30, 24, 18, 12)$.

This can be checked easily with Magma or GAP.
However I agree it lacks subtelty. One can probably use part $b)$ to build a smarter answer.

For the second part, I would suggest this.

It is well known that a dihedral group can be generated by two involutions as follows: $$D_{n}=\langle s,t \mid s^2=t^2=e, (st)^n=e \rangle$$
On the other hand, a cyclic group of order $k$ is generated by a unique element of order $k$: $$C_k= \langle r \mid r^k=e \rangle$$
Now take an integer $k\geq 3$ such that $k\mid n$. Hence there exists $p \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $pk=n$. Considering $s,t$ as in the presentation of $D_n$, one has $$(st)^n = e$$ and thus $$((st)^p)^k = e$$ that is to say, there exists an element $r := (st)^p$ of order $k$ in $D_n$.

Therefore there exists $H < D_n$ such that $$H= \langle r \mid r^k=e \rangle$$ i.e. $H$ is a cyclic group of order $k$. Unicity is a consequence of the fact that $r$ is uniquely determined as soon as $k$ is not $2$. In this case, any involution generates a cyclic group of order $2$.

I hope I answered your question.

Comment: It's not true that $r$ is uniquely determined, because various powers of $r$ will also have order $k$. Also, the uniqueness depends on the fact that all of the elements of $D_n$ that are not powers of $st$ have order 2.